# *ADVICE* Intuition about techniques for disproving the existence of simple groups of given order

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory, advice

Looking for some feedback on how to know when to use the different techniques for disproving there are no simple groups of a given order.

the techniques being:

1) counting elements

2) using subgroups of small order

3) permutation representations

4) using p-subgroups of different primes

5) normalizers of the intersections Sylow p-groups

Comment: The transfer theorems, particularly Burnside's Transfer Theorem are also very useful for proving groups of given orders are not simple.

Comment: @DerekHolt Okay I will remember that. From what I can tell there isn't a great way of knowing which technique to use.